# roomdb data -> homefragment of spinner

Tags: java, android

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM teaminfo GROUP BY teamName")
    Single<List<TeamInfo>> showTeam_Team();
```

How to display teamName in Roomdb in spinner in homefragment??

Is it better to get the ArrayListlist in settingadapter or the team in roomdb?